# Shortcut key for moving between windows in the Atom editor?

Tags: macos, ide, editor, atom-editor

I'm trying to move over from Sublime Text 2 to Githubs new code editor [Atom](http://atom.io). One thing I can't figure out: Is there a shortcut key for moving between open windows? The default global OSX shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> does not work in Atom and there seems to be no menu option in the app.

I'm on Atom 0.76 and OSX 10.9.2.

Comment: cmd-` works for switching between windows for me. If it borked somehow, maybe a package you installed is hijacking it. From cmd-shift-p type 'keybindings', then check in there.

Comment: I tried hijacking the `CMD-\`` keybinding with a custom keybinding in `keymap.cson`, but the OSX default still works for me. Not sure why this isn't working for you. Any updates or still having troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, either Atom or an installed package, was hijacking the global <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut, preventing it from working inside Atom. My solution was to remap the global OSX shortcut to occur on <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> instead.

Thanks to Kyle Kelly for pointing out that this might be the problem!

Comment: That's not a great solution. I want to keep the same shortcuts - I have muscle memory! When I press CMD-` I get the project explorer appear and disappear instead of switching windows. I have nothing in my keymap.